# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am new to android programming and google map v2.I am trying to draw a route using google map v2 in my android app. The problem is , whenever i run the code it gives inflate exception. I am not being able to figure it out what is causing this problem. I am following this website 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/.
Following are my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Initializing 
        mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);           

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already map contain destination location 
                if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
                    mMarkerPoints.clear();
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                    drawMarker(startPoint);
                }

                drawMarker(point);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){                  
                    LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }                   
            }
        });         
    }       
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;          

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;      

    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }



/** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }       
}

/** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject; 
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                points.add(position);                       
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);                            
    }           
}   


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
    mMarkerPoints.add(point);

    // Creating MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position of the marker
    options.position(point);

    /** 
     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
     */
    if(mMarkerPoints.size()==1){
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    }else if(mMarkerPoints.size()==2){
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    }

    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);      
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
    if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));        

        drawMarker(point);          
    } 

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}   
}
```

Below is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT errors:

```
  10-21 11:14:31.220: I/ActivityThread(2739): Switching default density from 160 to 120
    10-21 11:14:31.640: D/AndroidRuntime(2739): Shutting down VM
    10-21 11:14:31.650: W/dalvikvm(2739): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9ceab648)
    10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     ... 11 more
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     ... 21 more
10-21 11:19:32.260: I/Process(2739): Sending signal. PID: 2739 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this. This is worked for me.

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[And can see my git:](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apis/tree/master/WhereAmI)

**Manifesto file:**

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="key is here" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat clearly said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 5089000 but found 0. You must have the following declaration within the element: 10-21 11:14:31.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): at
```

You need to add Google play services version as `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

### Manifest.xml seems like:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    .......
    ......
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_Key" />

   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml also use uses-permission for the followings

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.

-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```